# Difference between Artinian and Noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian, artinian

I'm somewhat confused over the definition of Artinian and Noetherian rings.

A Noetherian ring is a ring in which there are no infinite chains of nested ideals. That is, if $I_i$ are some ideals in a ring $R$, which satisfy the condition $I_1\subset I_2 \subset ... \subset I_n \subset...$, then $\exists$ integer $N$ such that $I_N = I_m$ for all $m\ge N$.

An Artinian ring is a ring in which there are no infinite chains of nested ideals, but... if $I_i$ are some ideals in a ring $R$, which satisfy the condition $I_1\supset I_2 \supset ... \supset I_n \supset...$, then $\exists$ integer $N$ such that $I_N = I_m$ for all $m\ge N$.

But what is the difference between the Noetherian and the Artinian conditions? Can't we rewrite the ascending chain in the Noetherian case as a descending chain, and vice versa?

Comment: It suffices to give an example of one that is not the other.  $\mathbb{Z}$ is Noetherian but not Artinian.  There is no infinite ascending chain, but $\ldots \subset(8)\subset(4)\subset(2)$ is a descending chain.  Ponder these two statements for a while.

Comment: @BobJones Do you mean there is no infinite descending chain? I thought an ascending chain is a chain which begins from a smallest set and ascends to a bigger one.

Comment: You are correct in your definition.  But do you believe $(2)\supset (4)\supset (8)\supset\ldots$ is ascending or descending?

Comment: I think it's infinitely descending, since we begin from largest and descend to smaller and smaller, ad infinitum.

Comment: Exactly.  So $\mathbb{Z}$ HAS infinitely descending ideal chains, namely the one I just gave.  So it is not Artinian.  It is a PID, though, so it is Noetherian.

Comment: It turns out that artinian rings are noetherian, but it is far from obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't just rewrite an infinite ascending chain as an infinite descending chain or vice versa.  For instance, suppose you have an ascending chain $$I_1\subset I_2 \subset \dots \subset I_n \subset\dots$$ and want to get a descending chain $$J_1\supset J_2 \supset \dots \supset J_n \supset\dots$$
What are you going to define $J_1$ to be?  You can't make it $I_1$, since that's the smallest ideal in the chain, and $J_1$ needs to be the largest instead.  If you made $J_1$ be $I_2$, you could then make $J_2$ be $I_1$, but then you wouldn't be able to define $J_3$.  If you made $J_1$ be $I_3$ you could define $J_2=I_2$ and $J_3=I_1$, but then you would have no way to define $J_4$.  And so on.

For a similar phenomenon that should be familiar, there is an infinite ascending chain of natural numbers, namely $0\leq 1\leq 2\leq 3\leq\dots$.  But there is no infinite descending chain of natural numbers, since if you start such a chain at $n$, you can only ascend $n$ times before you run out of natural numbers!

Comment: My understanding was that we could rewrite $I_1\subset I_2 \subset \dots \subset I_n \subset\dots$ as $...\supset I_n\supset \dots\supset I_2 \supset I_1$, hence my confusion. Also, if $R$ is Noetherian then $I_1\subset I_2  \subset I_n$ can be rewritten as $I_n\supset \dots\supset I_2 \supset I_1$, so it is also Artinian.

Comment: You can write that, but that's not an "infinite descending chain" for the purposes of the definition of an Artinian ring.

Comment: So the idea is that every infinite ascending or descending chain must have a beginning element? Then this greatly clarifies the definition. Unfortunately, this important note was not given in my book or elsewhere I searched.

Comment: Well, the definition you quoted does not actually use the term "infinite descending chain".  It just writes $I_1\supset I_2 \supset ... \supset I_n \supset...$.  Notice that this is simply not the same as $...\supset I_n\supset \dots\supset I_2 \supset I_1$.

Comment: I thought by "infinite" they meant infinite from any end, even two ends at once.

Comment: But then, as I pointed out above, does Noetherian imply Artinian?

Comment: No?  As I've said, you can't interchange infinite ascending chains and infinite descending chains to deduce Artinian from Noetherian or vice versa.